# std::sort in c++?

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting, vector, containers

I want to sort a `vector` using `sort` algorithm in C++.

`str` is the name of `std::vector<int>` I want to sort.

What's the difference between this:

```
std::sort(str.rend(),str.rbegin())
```

and this:

```
std::sort(str.begin(),str.end())
```

Comment: I think you mean `std::`, not `str.`.

Comment: @ofey I think you should update the question to clearly identify that you meant (or did not mean) `std::sort`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming you intend to use `std::sort` to sort the string (since neither `std::vector` nor `std::string` have a `sort` method), the first statement is incorrect and leads to **undefined behaviour** (UB):

```
std::sort(str.rend(),str.rbegin());
```

Here, `std::sort` will attempt to dereference `str.rend()`, which is a "past the end" iterator. De-referencing such an iterator is UB.

A correct use of reverse iterators would be

```
std::sort(str.rbegin(),str.rend());
```

This would result in the string/vector being sorted in descending order.

Answer (score 3):

The iterators in the standard library on lots of containers and other things (like `std::string`) have a `reverse` variety which begin with `r` [(`rbegin()`, `rend` and the like)](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/rbegin). These will iterate in the reverse-sequential order. Using just `begin` and `end` will sort your string in the correct format from start to finish.

Try to avoid using the reverse iterators and just use the regular `begin()` and `end()` on your strings:

```
std::string str = "bacd";
std::sort( str.begin(),str.end() );
std::cout << str << std::endl; // should produce "abcd" on your output, without quotes
```

Edit:

So... you want `vector<int>` to be sorted instead? If so, do the same as above, except call `std::sort` with the `begin()` and `end()` of your `std::vector<int>`.